# Update url query params based on object properties

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I'm trying to update my url based on an object and its properties.

The url would be `http://www.mywebsite.com/f/o` and I would like to update its query params based on this object properties

```
queryObject = {
  example1: ['param1', 'param2'],
  example2: ['param3'],
}
```

so in this case, the complete url would be `http://www.mywebsite.com/f/o?example1=param1,param2&example2=param3`

The object properties are updated when the user clicks on list elements so the number of properties and indexes in arrays may vary.

Can you help me achieve that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let queryObject = {
  example1: ['param1', 'param2'],
  example2: ['param3'],
}

// creating a new URL
const url = new URL('http://www.mywebsite.com/f/o')


// adding/appending queryObject key - value pairs to URL query params
Object.entries(queryObject).forEach(([key, value])=> {
    url.searchParams.append(key, value.join(','))
})

console.log(url)
// logs:-> http://www.mywebsite.com/f/o?example1=param1%2Cparam2&example2=param3

// decoding encoded characters in url
console.log(decodeURIComponent(url))
// logs:-> http://www.mywebsite.com/f/o?example1=param1,param2&example2=param3
```

**To UPDATE the current pages URL's query params with the new url**

```
document.location.search = url.search
```